# Understanding array indexing in R

Tags: arrays, r

The [R documentation on arrays](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Arrays) states

> The values in the data vector give the values in the array in the same order as they would occur in FORTRAN, that is "column major order," **with the first subscript moving fastest and the last subscript slowest**.

It then later gives [a clarifying example](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-matrices) of this by loading data into a two dimensional array:

```
 > x <- array(1:20, dim=c(4,5))   # Generate a 4 by 5 array.
 > x
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    5    9   13   17
 [2,]    2    6   10   14   18
 [3,]    3    7   11   15   19
 [4,]    4    8   12   16   20
```

From experience with other languages, I would think `x[1, 2]`, rather than `x[2, 1]`, would be `2`, but this is pretty easy to adjust my thinking to. However, just as quickly as I perform my mental model shift, the next example smashes it apart:

```
 > i <- array(c(1:3,3:1), dim=c(3,2))
 > i                             # i is a 3 by 2 index array.
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    3
 [2,]    2    2
 [3,]    3    1
 > x[i]                          # Extract those elements
 [1] 9 6 3
```

So, I can see what happened here is that we extracted elements `x[1, 3]`, `x[2,2]`, and `x[3, 1]`. Okay, but doesn't this run completely counter to above claim of "column major order"?

From what I had understood, `i` should have been a *2 by 3* array, and R should have interpreted `x[i]` as `x[i[1, 1], i[2, 1]], x[i[1, 2], i[2, 2]], ...`. However, what we observe is that, instead, R did `x[i[1, 1], i[1, 2]], x[i[2, 1], i[2, 2]], ...`

Is this a fundamental inconsistency in R, or have I completely misunderstood the documentation?

Comment: which other languages do you mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"column major order" only means that **internally** matrices are vectors ordered column by column; see that

```
x[1:20]
```

is `1, 2, 3, ..., 19, 20`. Dimensions are ordered as usual in science -- first rows, then columns, then depth, then hyperdepth...
The third example is tricky: if `i` has the same number of columns that `x` has dimensions, it is interpreted as vectorized selection. If not, both `i` and `x` are flattered to by-column vectors and simple vector indexation rules apply... for instance `x[t(i)]` is `1:20[c(1,3,2,2,3,1)]`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a different thing altogether. As you note, the 2-column matrix is used as coordinates to get elements of x. It's an almost arbitrary design choice whether you use 2-column or 2-row matrices to do this, it's not related to the way matrices are filled.

The R guys chose 2-column.

Comment: There was another answer added that should have (probably) been an answer to this post. I have attached a [screenshot of the now deleted answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6wHOs.png) to help those users with less than 10k reputation (which might be of help to them). Sorry for the inconvenience, regards.