# Smart and Fast Indexing of multi-dimensional array with R

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

This is another step of my battle with multi-dimensional arrays in R, previous question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803814/apply-a-function-to-a-multi-dimensional-array-r-vs-matlab)  :)

I have a big R array with the following dimensions:

```
> data = array(..., dim = c(x, y, N, value))
```

I'd like to perform a sort of bootstrap comparing the mean (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631165/arithmetic-mean-on-a-multidimensional-array-on-r-and-matlab-drastic-difference) for a discussion about it) obtained with:

```
> vmean = apply(data, c(1,2,3), mean)
```

With the mean obtained sampling the `N` values randomly with replacement, to explain better if `data[1,1,,1]` is equals to [v1 v2 v3 ... vN] I'd like to replace it with something like [v_k1 v_k2 v_k3 ... v_kN] with k values sampled with `sample(N, N, replace = T)`.

Of course I want to AVOID a `for` loop. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755434/understanding-array-indexing-in-r) but I don't know how to perform an efficient indexing of this array avoiding a loop through `x` and `y`.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: the important thing here is that I want a different sample for each sample in the fourth (value) dimension, otherwise it would be simple to do something like:

```
> dataSample = data[,,sample(N, N, replace = T), ]
```

Comment: " for loops worse than *apply" is an urban legend.  So you might just want to do `for(j in 1:{value of N}) mean(data[,,j,])` with of course whatever sort of replacement instructions you desire added into the loop.

Comment: In fact I was looking for a vectorised solution, something like http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Array-indexing

Comment: OK, I'll see what I can gin up . Or see if `vectorize()` is fast enough.

Comment: I don't know what the package `boot` uses under the hood, but you need to define the estimation as a function that takes an index vector.

Answer (score 0):

Also there's the compiler package which speeds up for loops by using a Just In Time compiler.
Adding thes lines at the top of your code enables the compiler for all code.

```
require("compiler")
compilePKGS(enable=T)
enableJIT(3)
setCompilerOptions(suppressAll=T)
```